# Get sum of column in a join query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the query ...

```
  $productInfo = "SELECT list.* , production.*, Sum(production.units) AS totalQty
      FROM  production
      LEFT JOIN list
      ON list.id = production.com_id
      WHERE id = '$productID'
      AND production.userid = $userID";
```

For some reason this only returns 1 row and the sum. The table has 2 rows and they should both be returned.

If I remove the Sum(production.units) AS totalQty it returns the 2 rows but I won't be able to retrieve the sum.

What is the best way around this?
Thanks

Comment: Why not just sum it yourself in PHP?

Comment: sum() is an aggregate function. Its also going to be very difficult with the select * statements. try "Select t.column, t2.column, sum(t1.column) group by t.column, t2.column). NOTE: Not correct SQL just example to get aggregation demo'd If this doesn't illuminate enough I can expand more in an answer if you like.

Comment: Is production unit per user or per production.com_id for the sum?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT l.*, Sum(p.units) AS totalQty
FROM  production p LEFT JOIN
      list l
      ON l.id = p.com_id
WHERE l.id = '$productID' AND p.userid = $userID
GROUP BY l.id;
```

Actually, the `left join` doesn't make sense in the order you have it.  You might intend:

```
SELECT l.*, Sum(p.units) AS totalQty
FROM  list l LEFT JOIN
      production p 
      ON l.id = p.com_id AND p.userid = $userID
WHERE l.id = '$productID' AND 
GROUP BY l.id;
```

This will give you each list with the sum of production for that user.

Answer (score 0):

A stored function is a special kind stored program that returns a single value. You use stored functions to encapsulate common formulas or business rules that are reusable among SQL statements or stored programs.

```
    DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION mysum(p_creditLimit double,product_id Integer,user_id Interger) RETURNS VARCHAR(10)
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE lvl varchar(10);

  DECLARE select_var VARCHAR(500);
  SET select_var = (SELECT list.* , production.*, Sum(production.units) AS totalQty
      FROM  production
      LEFT JOIN list
      ON list.id = production.com_id
      WHERE id = product_id
      AND production.userid = user_id limit 1);
  RETURN select_var;
END
```

and simply call your SQL query

```
 $productInfo = "SELECT list.* , production.*, mysum(production.units,".$productID.",".$userID.") AS totalQty
      FROM  production
      LEFT JOIN list
      ON list.id = production.com_id
      WHERE id = '".$productID."'
      AND production.userid = $userID";
```

now $productInfo return all rows.

> source http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-stored-function/